# Powershell script to list users who are not part of two groups

Tags: powershell

There are two groups in our environment 'contractors' and 'employees' , I  need to write a script that lists all users who are not part of both the groups, can some one help me with it.

```
$n = Get-ADGroupMember "Contractor" | Sort-Object |
     foreach {Get-ADUser $_.name | select name}
$group = "Employee" 

foreach ($u in $n) {
    $get = (Get-ADUser $u.Name -Properties * | Select-Object memberof) 

    if ($get.memberof -match $group) { 
        Write-Host $u.name " is ok. They're in both groups." 
    } else { 
        Write-Host $u.Name " is not a member" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. Show us the code you have so far and explain what particular problem you ran into, and we'll help you improve from there.

Comment: I am not getting the correct output , attached the script I have tried

Comment: Please edit your question. As you can see code tends to become unreadable in a comment. If you're not getting correct output you also need to provide sample input as well as actual and desired output.

Comment: Did you get any errors when you ran this code? If yes link post error code

Comment: The error I am getting is I am getting list of users that are part of either group(Contractor or Employee), I need an output of users who are not part of both the groups

Comment: If you used more descriptive variable names, your code would be so much easier for others to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
$AllUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties memberof
foreach ($User in $AllUsers) {
   if (($User.memberof -match "Employee") -and ($User.memberof -match "Contractor")) {
       Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$($User.samaccountname) in both groups"
   } else {
       Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$($User.samaccountname) not in both groups"
   }
}
```

Comment: This is working thanks ,I will mark this as answered

Comment: Great, thanks for the editing Matt :). please mark if your happy with the answer.

Comment: I suspect the logic is off and that OP needs all users who are not in one of the groups.  I suspect that the users need to be in one or the other but not both.  Either way, OP forgot to upvote to give credit, and to mark answered.

Comment: I thinkt so "I need to write a script that lists all users who are not part of both the groups", either in none of the groups or in one of the groups.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your script, try this:

```
$n = get-adgroupmember "Contractor" | sort-object |foreach {get-aduser $_.SamAccountName} 
$group = "Employee" 
Foreach ($u in $n){ 
    $get = (get-aduser $u.SamAccountName -Properties * | Select-Object memberof)
        if ($get.memberof -match $group) { 
            Write-Host "$($u.name)  is ok. They're in both groups." } 
        Else { write-host $($u.name) " is not a member" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow 
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hi,I am still getting the same output , its listing the users of 'Contractors' group

Comment: It should users from Employee?

Comment: No...it should list users not part of 'Employee' and 'Contractor'

Comment: The result of your script never can be true (not part of 'Employee' and 'Contractor') because your query is based on members of your 'Contractor' group..., so the user account that you check exist by default in   'Contractor' group.